# How do I allocate a pointer that is a data member of a singleton class?

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

I have a singleton class i am using for global data. Here it is:

```
class Global
{
private:
   Global(void);           // Never invoked
public:
   static string bsDatabaseName;
   static string bsDatasourceName;
   static TStringList *ptrList;
};

string Global::bsDatasourceName;
string Global::bsDatabaseName;
TStringList Global::*ptrList;
```

My question is, how/where do I allocate memory for ptrList?  Just having the above compiles fine, but if I try to allocate memory to that pointer in code I get a linker error. This is the first time I have tried to use a pointer this way.

TIA
Fred Emmerich

Comment: that is not a Singleton, its a class of which no instances can be created with static members

Comment: That looks like the [monostate](https://wiki.c2.com/?MonostatePattern) pattern.

Comment: Show your failed attempt. Hard to help if you don't show what's wrong.

Comment: `TStringList Global::*ptrList;` is fantasy code. That should be `TStringList *Global::ptrList;` . Include an accurate [mcve] including the verbatim, *specific* steps you're using to build your code, and verbatim, *specific* error messaging you're receiving whilst doing so.

Comment: That is the whole code. I copied that method years ago and it was called a singleton, which does look different than what I have seen described lately.  Apparently my nomenclature of Global::*ptrList was wrong and when I changed it to your suggestion it compiles fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FWE1 It is not a singleton. Even we're talking about 20 years ago, it still wouldn't be called a singleton. Singletons are objects that can only have 1 instance at a time. You would create an instance from a helper method that checks if there's already an existing instance and returns that instance, if not, create a new instance or throw some error for handling. That's all there is to it. You'll find a lot of these classes with a method called `getInstance()` or something along the lines. There's some variance of singletons where some implementations limit it to specific scopes.

Comment: The class I copied has all static members, so isn't it functionally the same since all the data members are static?  What would be the purpose of a real singleton?